# Scala o/p capturing

Tags: scala

> > Trying to capture o/p of val b {Looking to capture value of call id} into a variable for further processing but 
> >       everytime i try to use the o/p of val b , return an empty list.
> >         Prints perfectly on console

#### CODE

```
`val l = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().toList
val b =  l.view.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1.contains("INVITE sip:")).foreach { 
  case (s, i) => l.view(i-1, 
i+3).filterNot(_.contains("Via:")).foreach(println(_))
  }
    println(b) //Not printing anything`
```

### Function Output (Console)

Mar 28 07:29:44.384583 Received UDP message from socket 7 (UDP_CH 
  10.16.XXX.XXX:XXXX):
  INVITE sip:410133@10.16.XXX.XXX:XXXX;user=phone;transport=UDP SIP/2.0

Call-ID: `3oNDcusoym86NijUpnyHPA..`
  Mar 28 07:30:59.709565 Received UDP message from socket 7 (UDP_CH 
  10.16.XXX.XXX:XXXX):
  INVITE sip:410106@10.16.XXX.XXX:XXXX;user=phone;transport=UDP SIP/2.0

Call-ID: `LFJ11WJOpKp2NUZxOe1z0g..`

Comment: Please reformat this as a proper question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` method returns `Unit` (i.e. `void`) so the value of `b` will be `Unit`.

If you want to keep the results then you need to replace the outer `foreach` with `map` and remove the inner `foreach`.

You can also combine the `filter` into the `map` by using `collect`:

```
val b = l.view.zipWithIndex.collect {
  case (s, i) if s.contains("INVITE sip:") =>
    l.view(i-1, i+3).filterNot(_.contains("Via:"))
}
```

And if you want the results rather than a `view` on the results, do this

```
val b = l.zipWithIndex.collect {
  case (s, i) if s.contains("INVITE sip:") =>
    l.slice(i-1, i+3).filterNot(_.contains("Via:"))
}
```

Comment: I got the output , but i am still getting the complete o/p , i am just looking to  extract all call id values  `3oNDcusoym86NijUpnyHPA.. ` , `LFJ11WJOpKp2NUZxOe1z0g..` discarding all the other contents of string. 
I was looking for the regex , but to have something that takes a prefix and suffix and extract the middle portion of string. As their is no standard value of call id.